# Basic Django urls (home : name not defined)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-settings

I'm getting the error  :

```
File "E:\2- Formations\1-Programmation\3- PYTHON\1- DASH\1- Apprentissage\dashsite\dashsite\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
path('',include(home.urls)),
NameError: name 'home' is not defined
```

When I try to runserver / migrate.

I'm sucepting a wrong setting cause it should work : [My folders organisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBY8F.png)

**Settings.py code which should alowwed my to use the home. :**

```
from pathlib import Path
from django import apps

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dashsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dashsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**Project : urls.py (dir dashsite):**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include(home.urls)),
```

**App: urls.py (dir home) :**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('',views.home, name='home')
]
```

**views.py (dir home) :**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request) :
    return render(request,'home/welcome.html')
```

Thank's for your help and the time you take.
Arthur

Comment: you forgot to put the quotes in path('',include('home.urls')),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include the app home in `installed` app in settings.py,
Put quotes around the `home.urls` in base URL like so:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('home.urls'))
]
```

I believe this should work now.

Comment: if this solves your problem, mark this as the answer.